# Why $(\cos t, \sin t)$ is not a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Consider the map $f: [0,2 \pi ) \to S^1 \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ defined by $t \mapsto (\cos t, \sin t)$. It is clear that $f$ is continuous and bijective.

It is not open and therefore not a homeomorphism. My question is: is it ok to argue as follows? Here is my argument:

Consider $[0,\pi) \subseteq [0,2\pi)$. Then this set is open. Its image is the upper semi circle minus the point $(-1,0)$ which is not open. Therefore $f$ is not open.

Comment: I would add one word for the sake of greater clarity: it’s image is the *closed* upper semicircle minus the that point. Otherwise it’s fine.

Comment: A more global argument is that only one among domain and the codomain of $f$ is compact.

Comment: One could also use that removing any point (except $\{0\}$) disconnects the domain, but does not disconnect $S^1$.